# How to deploy in visual studio with FTPS

Tags: iis, ftp, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022, ftps

IIS has an option for FTP with required SSL (FTPS) otherwise your credentials, including password, are sent in plain text over the network or to server. Can visual studio deploy via FTP with security enabled (SSL)? Every time I try I keep getting cannot connect but if I disable SSL it works.

Comment: Could you tell me what error message you got? What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I am using visual studio pro 2019 or I can use visual studio community 2022. In IIS if I do not require ssl for the ftp site then the connection says validate when I click test connection in visual studio in the edit connection section.  However, as soon as I switch on require SSL in IIS then clicking validate returns error "Unable to open the website "ftp://blah.blah". Request denied for policy reasons."

Comment: Oh wow I just noticed If I put FTPS://blah.blah in the server and site locations it then validates!

Comment: I'm very glad that your problem has been solved. If possible, I suggest you can write the solution as an answer and post it, which may help other community members to solve similar problems, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use ftp w/ssl you need to make the server name and/or the site location ftps://whateverserveraddressis.com